# My PS4 controller will not connect after rest mode

Tags: ps4, controllers

I recently got a ps4, but whenever I put it into rest mode, the controllers will get a white bar and will not respond when I try to press the PS button. I am forced to shut it down, and whenever I have progress, I lose it. I can’t press the reset button because it still doesn’t work. Is there anyway to fix this? Is it a temporary software issue that may be fixed later?

Comment: I have no clue how a PS4 controller works, but I wonder if its kinda like a gameboy cartridge battery. All of it is saved on a flash memory that gets wiped if there is no current going through it. If the separate battery that has it is dead, the moment you shut down your controller the configuration is wiped.

Comment: Except it only connects when the console is turned off completely, or there isn’t current flowing through it. So it is the other way around

Comment: Try factory resetting your PS4 ("Initialize PS4"). That seems to have worked for other people.

Comment: I had just done that when the problem started popping up